# Contour integration of a function $(z-a)^{-m}(z-b)^{-n}$

Tags: integration, complex-integration

Let $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Moreover let's find $a, b$ such that both are inside a contour $C$.

I am asked to prove that
$$\int_C\frac1{(z-a)^m}\frac1{(z-b)^n}\,\mathrm{d}z=0.$$

Cauchy's theorem doesn't work here unfortunately because partial fraction decomposition seems pretty impossible.

How can it be done?

Comment: Do you know of deformation of curves and the triangle inequality (sometimes, with an additional estimate, the ML-inequality)? If not, take it as a hint.

Comment: Perhaps you could use the Rosidue theorem?

Comment: Substitute $z=w^{-1}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I tried but unfortunately I don't know what to do next. Maybe a bigger hint, please?

Comment: That substitution pushes those poles **outside** the contour....

Comment: What would be your guess first? What would be the answer if $a=b=0$?

Comment: @copper.hat For $a = b = 0$ it's pretty obvious. Since both $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$ then $n + m > -1$. So the integral is equal to $0$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I'm sorry but I really don't see how they are pushed outside the contour. It might be huge after all.

Comment: @Hendrra: Sorry, that was misleading. I will add a residue based answer below shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all singularities of the integrand
$$f(z)=\frac1{(z-a)^m(z-b)^n}$$
are inside the integration contour the simplest way to evaluate the integral is to use:

$$\oint_C f(z)dz=-2\pi i\operatorname{Res}(f(z),\infty)
=2\pi i \operatorname{Res}\left[\frac1{w^2}f\left(\frac1w\right),0\right]\\
=2\pi i \operatorname{Res}\left[\frac1{w^2}\frac{w^{m+n}}{(1-aw)^m(1-bw)^n},0\right]
=2\pi i\delta_{m+n,1}.
$$

Thus the integral is zero provided that $m+n\ne1$. If $m,n$  are both positive this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\int_C {1 \over (z-a)^m (z-b)^n } dz = 2 \pi i (\operatorname{res} (f,a)+\operatorname{res} (f,b))$.

$\operatorname{res} (f,a) = {1 \over (m-1)!} \lim_{z \to a} {d^{m-1} \over dz^{m-1}}{1 \over (z-b)^n } = (-1)^n { (n+m-2)! \over (m-1)! (n-1)!} (b-a)^{-n-m+1}$

$\operatorname{res} (f,b) = {1 \over (n-1)!} \lim_{z \to b} {d^{n-1} \over dz^{n-1}}{1 \over (z-a)^m } = (-1)^m { (n+m-2)! \over (m-1)! (n-1)!} (a-b)^{-n-m+1}$

Adding the two together yields zero.